# What's the proper return value for MVC4 WebAPI when HTTP request is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, http, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI for exposing json services. If a HTTP GET request received but the URL is invalid (e.g. an invalid id), what should I return as best practice? I tried to return null and the response is a null string, is this a good way for handling this?

Comment: URL is invalid (e.g. an invalid id) ? what the id ? id is parameter? 

ex `http:example.com?id=(not valid)`

Comment: Sorry, I mean a non-existing id specified in the URL. for this case, what should return?

Comment: if i were you i will return 500 application error, and if you using ajax on jquery will be handle on error $.ajax call function

Comment: 500 is the HTTP response status code, but for the WebAPI you still need to return a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) is a very good read when starting with ASP.NET Web Api.

From what I understand of your question, you should use this

```
public void GetProduct(int id)
{
    if (_service.GetProduct(id) == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

[A complete list of HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx)